# Regular Expression on Strings

Tags: regex

I wrote this regular expression in http://www.regexr.com/

Regular Expression: `(^A.*\..\s)\|((\sS.*:\sA.*,\sN.....\s))\|(\sN.+)/g`

Text:

> AT1G01010.1 | Symbols: ANAC001, NAC001 | NAC domain containing protein 1 
>   | chr1:3760-5630 FORWARD LENGTH=429

I'm able to detect the 1st String|2nd String| 3rd String| in the above text.

I would like to eliminate the 2nd part (" Symbols: ANAC001, NAC001 ") in the above text using the regular expression. Could anyone help? Or I need a regular expression to detect only the 1st and 3rd String.

Comment: Did you want to remove the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following regex since you are already using the beginning of string `^` anchor.

```
^(A[^|]+)\s\|[^|]+\|\s*([^|]+)\s\|
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wQ1jU5/1)

Comment: Note: Your match results are in capturing group `1` and `2`

Comment: Thanks 4 live demo . Worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? the regular ex that you provide that will search the whole text and return you the one that match. so you are treating the regex as a whole. if you want grab just the 1st part and the 3st part, then you need to do two seperate regex  on the same text twice and merge the result together.

Answer (score 0):

try ?:

```
(^A.*\..\s)\|(?:\sS.*:\sA.*,\sN.....\s)\|(\sN.+)
```

Comment: Nope.Its matching all the three strings.